# Basic question about gradient for nominal regression

Tags: math, regression, gradient

Say that we want to binary-classify images using a sigmoid function with the entropy-loss function. This algorithm is quite slow.

The sigmoid function is:

[image: Sigmoid]

I find that this could be traced to the $L(y,y') = -log(y')$ for $y=1$ and $L(y,y') = log(1-y')$,  for $y=0$.

**EDIT** But actually that is a great, desired property! The problem is the
second term in the total derivative respect to the Loss ($L$):

$$dL = dL/dy * dy/dz ...$$

because it is $dy/dz$ is very small for large or small values of $z$:

[image: Sigmoid]

Linear regression wouldn't have this problem as that term is 1 (or non existent). But there could be an "explosion" of the gradient because of the $Loss = (y-y')^2$.

**Question**:
So I'd suggest to use a cutoff value for y' in, say, 10 if your labels are (-1 for not, 1 for yes).

Has this been tried before?  If so what were the results?

Is this a reasonable approach or would it just not work?

Comment: why are you saying that _the loss goes to 0 when we have a good prediction_ is a problem? also for MSE this holds

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia Can you check now? I expanded to my best.

Comment: Take the BCE and substitute x with the sigmoid function, and you will see that you have a linear gradient (BCE undoes the sigmoid)